# 'in cannot be resolved' Java Scanner

Tags: java, eclipse

I've recently been learning Java and decided as a little task to understand user input, I would create a times tables generator, for a user entered number. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tables {

public static void main( String[] args) {

    int IFactor, num, ans;  

    Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number to be the factor: ");
        String SFactor = Input.next();
        IFactor = Integer.parseInt(SFactor); 

        num = 1;

        while (num < 11) {   
            ans = num * IFactor;
            System.out.println(num + " * " + IFactor + " = " + ans);
            num++; 
        }

    }
    finally {
        in.close();
    }

}

}
```

I originally had an error when I was declaring the Scanner 'input' with Eclipse stating that there was a resource leak and that it wasn't closed. I did a bit of research and saw that inserting a try{ } and a finally { } with 'in.close();' would solve the problem. However, this wasn't the case as I now have the error: 'in cannot be resolved'.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What exception or error you getting. Can we have logs..

Comment: `in` is not declared by you. Its a property of `System` class of `InputStream` type

Comment: It's worth mentioning that in Java, you generally don't captialize variables. You capitalize types. So you're looking at `int factor`, `Scanner input`, `String factorString`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable name is `Input` and you are trying to do in.close().
It should be:

```
finally {
   Input.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in is not assigned to anything. 
You would have to close your scanner called Input.

```
 try{
// code
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
// Exception handling
}
finally{
        if(Input!=null){ 
         Input.close();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try with resources is the modern / recommended way to close `AutoCloseable` resources like `Scanner`. E.g.

```
try (Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    // do stuff with Input
}
```

and skip the `finally` block. `Input` will be closed when at the end of the `try` block or earlier if an exception is thrown. And you don't have to worry about it.

Check Item 7 in Effective Java for reasons to avoid `finally` block

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
finally {
    Input.close();
}
```

instead. Please note that with java, variable names begin with a lowercase letter generally (and Classes with an upperface) - so it would be better to rename that variable to `input? as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
finally {
    in.close();
}
```

You can try this code which uses try-with-resources. It is more java8, and you do not need the finally clause:

```
try(Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number to be the factor: ");
        String SFactor = Input.next();
        IFactor = Integer.parseInt(SFactor); 

        num = 1;

        while (num < 11) {   
            ans = num * IFactor;
            System.out.println(num + " * " + IFactor + " = " + ans);
            num++; 
        }

    }
```